# Django template - hide content based on time of day

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to hide a block in my template (base.html) if the time is not a weekday between 09:00 and 17:00.

I was thinking something like (very simplified):

```
{% if now is 09:00 and 17:00 on weekdays %}

#Show callback form

{% else %}

#We do not answer the phone before 09:00 and after 17:00 

{% endif %}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a flag in your `view.py`

```
import datetime

# In view
now = datetime.datetime.now()
call_us_now = False
if 9 < now.hour < 17:
   call_us_now = True

# Send 'call_us_now' to context
```

.

```
{# In template #}
{% if call_us_now %}
    {# Show callback form #}
{% else %}
    {# We do not answer the phone before 09:00 and after 17:00 #}
{% endif %]
```

Comment: I want to use this code on my base.html, so maybe a little difficult to implement your code on every view?

Comment: OK, you cannot (to my knowledge) use `{% now %}` in if statments.  If you had todays date in the context you coudl use that. Personally  I would look at context processors tehn and add the flag to all pages. - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use this code on my base.html, so maybe a little difficult
>   to implement your code on every view?

Write a custom `template context processor`. You can use this as a starting point:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

from django.conf import settings

def calling_flag(request):
    """ Sets the flag in the template if the current time is between CALL_HOURS """
    if settings.CALL_HOURS:
        now = datetime.now().time()
        start_time,end_time = settings.CALL_HOURS
        start_time = time(start_time[:2],start_time[-2:])
        end_time = time(end_time[:2],end_time[-2:])
        return {'IN_TIME': start_time <= now <= end_time}
```

Save it in a file inside an app. Lets say the app is called `feedback`, and you placed the above code in a file called `custom_template_flags.py` in the `feedback` directory. Next step, add it to your `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # -- your other context processors
    'feedback.custom_template_flags.calling_flag',
)
```

Finally, add your time range, again in `settings.py`:

```
CALL_HOURS = ('0900','1700')
```

Now, all templates will have `{{ IN_TIME }}` which will be either `True` or `False`.

Comment: Looks good! Is it possible to check if it is a weekday also? (mon-fri)